# missing keyword error while dropping a column

Tags: sql, oracle, alter

When i try to drop a column using the below command,

```
alter table <table_name> drop <column_name>;
```

am getting "missing keyword" error.

Getting the same error when am using column keyword also as below,

```
alter table <table_name> drop column <column_name>;
```

Answer (score 1):

`alter table <table_name> drop column <column_name>` works perfectly.

For example,

```
SQL> create table t(id number, text varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> desc t;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 TEXT                                               VARCHAR2(10)

SQL> alter table t drop column text;

Table altered.

SQL> desc t;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```sql
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP COLUMN column1;
```

or

```sql
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP (column1, column2, ...);
```

or even

```sql
ALTER TABLE table1 SET UNUSED (column1);
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP UNUSED COLUMNS;
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a7b2/1)** demo